# Concat vs push adding new array in react best practice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Many folks promote immutability because they use redux altogether with react, but I'm still seeing people using push instead of concat.

Take this code for example:

```
submitComment() {
  console.log('submitComment: '+JSON.stringify(this.state.comment))

  APIManager.post('/api/comment', this.state.comment, (err, response) => {
    if (err){
      alert(err)
      return
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
    let updateList = Object.assign([], this.state.list)
    updatedList.push(response.result)
    this.setState({
      list: updatedList
    })
  })
}
```

in this case does it matter at all? What's the issue with push above?

Comment: The shortest answer might be this: when you get to using `shouldComponentUpdate` in practice, you'll understand why it would have been better to go with immutable data structures. Of course I'm not saying immutable data structures are better per se, just that they are generally more feasible to integrate into `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: The author's choice to use `Object.assign` is a pretty unusual one. It's much more common to use `arr.slice()` to copy an array (and, I'm guessing, faster, since it'll be optimized for arrays, but I can't be sure). But, as @OriDori wrote, `concat` is good choice in this case.

Comment: @Jordan I think they were trying to mimic `const myArray = [...arr1, ...aray2]`, which I believe utilizes `Object.assign`.

Comment: @lux Not [per the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-arrayaccumulation). Array spread and object spread are different operations, despite using the same (pseudo-)operator. FWIW, [Babel uses `concat`](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015-loose%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&code=var%20a%20%3D%20%5B1%5D%3B%0Avar%20b%20%3D%202%3B%0Avar%20c%20%3D%20%5B%20...a%2C%20b%20%5D).

Comment: @Jordan Good to know! Always nice to have a TIL before 11am.

Comment: @Jordan arr.slice() to copy array? slice as I know is to delete an item from array?

Comment: @ZeaLith You're thinking of `splice`.

Comment: both are the same no? splice did not mutate the original array while slice mutate, no?

Comment: @ZeaLith No, they're not the same. `splice` removes and/or adds items to an array. `slice` returns a copy of part of the array. `arr.slice()` is the same as `arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1)`, ergo it returns a copy of the whole array.

Comment: @JohnWeisz Why would pushing to the array (w/o using Object.assign or array.slice) cause a problem when using shouldComponentUpdate?

Answer (score 8):

Immutability is used in react and not only because of redux. React component's state should not be mutated directly. According to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state):

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

In addition, [immutability](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data) also helps in reconciliation. If props are immutable, you can make a shallow equality check to see if it's changed or not, and render accordingly.

In your code `updatedList` is cloned to a new array using `Object#assign`. Now you can Array#push to the array, without changing the original one. Using Array#concat is a bit shorter, and more readable:

```
const updatedList = this.state.list.concat(response.result);
```